# How can I automatically remove duplicate sources.list entries?

Tags: ppa, updates

I try to install a new ppa entry and when I update from command line I received a duplicate (error) message. I know what meens that and how to solve manually with Ubuntu Tweak or command line. Is any automated way to solve this problem when I install duplicate entries? like a command which find the duplicates and erase them or a software.