# Using 13.04 I get "Duplicate sources.list entry" warnings from i386 and AMD64 packages

Tags: apt, software-sources, 13.04

I understand this was a bug in Oneric, but was fixed, so why is Raring trying to fetch both achetypes when I use APT in the terminal, and how do I fix it? I tried running YPPA and it says I have no duplicates. Initially, there were duplicates, which were removed by [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30585/how-can-i-automatically-remove-duplicate-sources-list-entries) handy little .PHP-based tool:

Results:

```
------------------------------------
sources.list Checker 0.01-Beta
Done By Mubarak Alrashidi (DeaDSouL)
------------------------------------
Total Lines:             164
Total Repositories:      32
Active Repositories:         32
Inactive Repositories:       0
Duplicated Repositories:     5
------------------------------------
Line:        Repositories:
83       deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring universe
117      deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
118      deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
155      deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
156      deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
------------------------------------
To un-do this, check the backup:
"/etc/apt/sources.list.bkp.2013-04-23_16-40-38"
```

So then I ran `apt-get update` again, but I'm still getting "duplicate" warnings, and these warnings relate to package requests for both i386 and AMD64.

Terminal Output:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-updates_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-updates_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-backports_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-backports_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-backports_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports/multiverse i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-backports_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_raring-security_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

And here's my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)]/ quantal main restricted
# deb cdrom:[Lubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Alpha amd64 (20130403)]/ raring main multiverse restricted universe
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.04 _Raring Ringtail_ - Release amd64 (20130420)]/ raring main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring multiverse universe restricted main #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates restricted universe main multiverse #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-backports universe restricted main multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security restricted universe main multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring universe
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
##### Duplicate Entry - Removed ##### deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring universe

## Added by Seann 19 Feb 2013 - Minecraft Map Overviewer
deb http://overviewer.org/    debian ./

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
##### Duplicate Entry - Removed ##### deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
##### Duplicate Entry - Removed ##### deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring multiverse restricted
## developers who want to ship their latest software.

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-backports restricted multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security restricted

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
##### Duplicate Entry - Removed ##### deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner
##### Duplicate Entry - Removed ##### deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu raring partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-proposed multiverse universe restricted main
deb http://download.learnfree.eu/repository/skss / #SKSS
deb-src http://download.learnfree.eu/repository/skss / #SKSS
```

So ... Thoughts, ideas, or suggestions?